# How to retrieve the title of the latest post in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a website that is based on Wordpress. My client wants to display the latest post snippet under the header on the main page. I was able to do that but instead of fetching the post's title in the loop it is fetching the page title and displaying it there.

Here is my code :

```
    <?php
 $postslist = get_posts('numberposts=1&order=DESC&orderby=date');
 foreach ($postslist as $post) :
    setup_postdata($post);
 ?>
 <div class="entry">
 <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
 <?php the_time(get_option('date_format')) ?><?php if (has_post_thumbnail() ) {
 the_post_thumbnail();
 } the_excerpt(); ?>
 </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I have also tried `get_the_title();` but it did not work as well.

[The SITE ITSELF](http://multiplestreammktg.com/internet-marketing-blog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked. There is a plugin called smart post lists that was not letting it work. Now it is working fine. 
It was my mistake to not disable it and test this. My code is correct.

Answer (score 2):

From wordpress codex
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array('numberposts' => 1);
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent )
   echo $recent["post_title"];
```

if you want to use the loop

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 1);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        ?>
            <div class="entry">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <?php the_time(get_option('date_format')) ?>  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>  
        <?php 
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I replaced my code with yours so yes, juste replace your code with the second code block

Comment: It did not work, I pasted the  code addid the php opening and closing tags but it did not work

Comment: It works on my site... what dosn't work ? is your post published ? with a date prior to now ?

Comment: Here, http://pastebin.com/CTqpRUZ1 and for the site I have given it in the edited answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100987/discussion-between-4127157-and-ianis).

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '1' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
<div class="entry">
            <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($recent['ID']); ?>"><?php echo $recent['post_title'] ?></a></h3>
<?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?> 
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent['ID'] ); ?>
<?php echo get_excerpt($recent['ID']); ?>
        </div>  
}
?>
```

Comment: What about the excerpt ?

Comment: Modified for excerpt.

Comment: Modified for post featured image.

Comment: Nothing is appearing on the site with this. See, I am not inserting this in index.php . I am inserting this in a widget on the index page, so I need to call the post in it. My code does call it there but it fails to retrieve the title that is my problem

Comment: I think the problem with your code in my situation is that it is trying to retriee the posts assuming that it is the index page or something, because had it got even on post, it would have made the div but it doesn't as I see when I inspect.

Comment: Where is the widget that you tested with located? is it a custom widget area?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100995/discussion-between-4127157-and-atif-tariq).